# Shell Script- Traversing sub directories using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to traverse through the sub directories under current directory. There are certain files that i want to access and process inside each sub--directories. Can anyone help how can I access files inside sub directories?

```
"
for dir in /home/ayushi/perfios/fraud_stmt/*; 
do echo $dir;


done;
"
```

This above script will echo all the sub directories. but instead of echoing I want to go inside the directories and access files that are present inside it.

Comment: use `ls` instead of `echo`

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home/ayushi/perfios/fraud_stmt/ -type f | while read fname; do
    : do something on $fname here
done
```

This will search for all files (i.e. not actual directories) from the specified directory downwards. Note that you should enclose "$fname" in double quotes, in case it contains spaces or other "odd" characters.

Comment: for dir in /home/ayushi/perfios/fraud_stmt/*;do find /home/ayushi/perfios/fraud_stmt/ -type f | while read fname;do: do echo $fname ; done


I have written like this , this throws error...Can you please elaborate

Comment: No, my script was the whole thing - you don't need the "for" loop at all, and only one "do" in the middle of the line. Just copy my code, and change ": do something on $fname here" to "echo $fname"

Answer (score 1):

An example using a recursive function

```
process_file() {
    echo "$1"
}

rec_traverse() {
    local file_or_dir
    for file_or_dir in "$1"/*; do
        [[ -d $file_or_dir ]] && rec_traverse "$file_or_dir"
        [[ -f $file_or_dir ]] && process_file "$file_or_dir"
    done
}

rec_traverse /home/ayushi/perfios/fraud_stmt
```

- `process_file` can be changed to do something on file.
- `"$1"/*` may be changed to `"$1"/* "$1"/.*` to match hidden directories but in this case special hard linked directories `.` and `..` must be filtered to avoid infinite loop.